# как сбросить fstream::get?

Tags: c++, файлы

Понадобилось пройтись по файлу циклом два раза, но во второй раз fstream::get возвращает false, как сделать так, чтоб он снова указывал на начало файла?

Comment: seekg не помог.

Comment: Приведите свой код. И еще - если вы хотите, чтоб на ваш комментарий обратили внимание - делайте его именным, ставя в начале @ и имя получателя.

Answer (score 0):

Для чтения, как я понимаю?

```
f.seekg(0);
```

Вот [тут](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) описание этой функции.